# Only one dynamically generated link is clickable

Tags: jquery, html

I have dynamically generated links on my page. What I want is when I click on any of the links, another page should be loaded using jquery. What happens now is that only the first link will load the desired page, while others are not clickable. How can I adjust my code below so all the links will load the page when clicked?

**HTML**

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<td style='text-align:center'>
 <a href='#' id='sub_add'><button class='btn btn-default'>Add</button></a>
</td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#sub_add').click(function(){
    $('#msg').load('another_page.php');
});
```

Comment: There is only one link in your code, so only the first link will work since there are no other.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're duplicating IDs. IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Why not just use that href as it is intended for it?

Comment: @Maantje OP is using .load() as an ajax request.

Comment: Please provide a more sample html. Your problem can't be replicated with the samples you've provided

Answer (score 0):

You should implement something like this (assuming the next two `div.msg` elements were dynamycally created) :

```
<div class="msg msg-1"></div>
<td style="text-align:center">
  <a href="#" class="sub_add" data-mgsid="1" data-page="another_page.php"><button class="btn btn-default">Add</button></a>
</td>

<div class="msg msg-2"></div>
<td style="text-align:center">
  <a href="#" class="sub_add" data-mgsid="2" data-page="another_page_2.php"><button class="btn btn-default">Add</button></a>
</td>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".sub_add", function(){
  $("msg-"+$(this).data("msgid")).load($(this).data("page"));
});
```